# Pandas - fill rows with nan based on index value

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe (simplified - the actual has 21 columns)):

```
0      262.0                   1.691667e+01                   1.568333e+01   
1      263.0                   1.280000e+01                   8.523529e+00   
2      264.0                   9.006250e+00                   1.498125e+01   
3      265.0                   1.174118e+01                   1.096471e+01   
4      266.0                   1.036316e+01                   1.504737e+01   
5      267.0                   1.012941e+01                   1.186471e+01   
6      275.0                   1.358571e+01                   1.640714e+01   
7      276.0                   1.444667e+01                   8.900000e+00   
8      277.0                   2.241111e+01                   9.011111e+00   
9      280.0                   2.183889e+01                   9.405556e+00   
10     282.0                   1.918125e+01                   1.468125e+01   
11     284.0                   1.412941e+01                   1.069412e+01   
12     285.0                   6.511111e+00                   2.394737e+01    
13     286.0                  -7.000000e-08                  -1.200000e-07   
14     290.0                   1.032941e+01                   6.788235e+00   
15     292.0                   9.077778e+00                   8.216667e+00   
16     293.0                   1.171579e+01                   8.257895e+00   
17     294.0                   6.464706e+00                   1.036471e+01   
18     315.0                  -1.300000e-07                  -1.100000e-07   
19     327.0                  -1.700000e-07                  -1.300000e-07   
20     354.0                   7.377778e+00                   1.699444e+01   
21     356.0                   1.359412e+01                   4.623529e+00   
22     373.0                   8.822222e+00                   1.103333e+01   
23    1371.0                  -1.500000e-07                  -1.000000e-07
```

And I need to set all column values to NaN for index >= 20, like so:

```
...
20     354.0                   NaN                  NaN  
21     356.0                   NaN                  NaN   
22     373.0                   NaN                  NaN  
23    1371.0                   NaN                  NaN
```

---

How do I achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need set second and third column use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[df.index >= 20, 1:] = np.nan
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'iloc'`?

Comment: @8-BitBorges - So `print (df)` is not DataFrame?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: @8-BitBorges - hmmm, it is weird, because `float` object is not DataFrame, not sure what is problem.

Comment: @8-BitBorges - Need set all without first? So use `df.iloc[df.index >= 20, 1:] = np.nan`

Answer (score 2):

```
Try iloc accessor

df.iloc[20:,1:]=np.nan
```